# Rellenar con ceros todos los registros de una tabla hasta que su longitud sea de 10 digitos

Tags: sql-server

tengo una tabla con muchos registros, estos tienen un campo código de tipo char(10).
Los registros tienen un código que ahora mismo oscila entre los 2 y los 8 caracteres, necesito rellenar todos los códigos con ceros a la izquierda hasta que tengan 10 dígitos.
La pregunta es si puedo realizar esto mediante una consulta, o me centro en hacerlo mediante un procedimiento?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El termino es "Zero padding", y lo puedes hacer así:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000000' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,Columna),''), 10)
       FROM TuTabla
```

Comment: Faltó convertir la columna a varchar para que ignore los espacios a la derecha.

Answer (score 3):

La duda sería si los ceros a la izquierda es algo que quieras mostrar o guardar. Teniendo la columna como char(10), no importa mucho en relación a espacio en disco, pero sí se debe de corregir el método para guardarlo.

Si es solo para visualizarlo, se puede hacer directamente en la consulta. Agrego una corrección al código de Patricio e incluyo ejemplos.

```
DECLARE @Codigos TABLE ( codigo char(10))
INSERT INTO @Codigos
VALUES
     ('1')
    ,('12')
    ,('123')
    ,('1234')
    ,('12345')
    ,('123456')
    ,('1234567')
    ,('12345678')
    ,('123456789')
    ,('1234567890');

SELECT *, 
        RIGHT('0000000000' + ISNULL(RTRIM(CAST( codigo as varchar(10))),''), 10),
        REPLICATE( '0', 10-LEN(codigo)) + codigo
FROM @Codigos;
```

Si la opción es guardarlos con los ceros de forma correcta, solo habría que hacer un UPDATE a todas las filas de la tabla para corregir los datos ya existentes y cambiar el método de guardado para que ya no sea necesario corregir datos.

```
DECLARE @Codigos TABLE ( codigo char(10))
INSERT INTO @Codigos
VALUES
     ('1')
    ,('12')
    ,('123')
    ,('1234')
    ,('12345')
    ,('123456')
    ,('1234567')
    ,('12345678')
    ,('123456789')
    ,('1234567890');

UPDATE @Codigos 
SET codigo = REPLICATE( '0', 10-LEN(codigo)) + codigo;

SELECT *
FROM @Codigos
```